# Search for Page by Website via Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook PHP SDK V4, I successfully obtained the Access Token. Is it possible to search for Pages with specific website?

Currently I use the following query to search for pages:

> https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=http:%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com&type=page&access_token=$access_token

However, this only searches by keyword, instead of searching against the website field of page. How can I modify the query to search against website field?

Comment: I think you can try https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/url and then parse the response to see if there is any page related with the searched url

Comment: nice idea, but the response does not provide any linkages to FB pages...

Comment: Similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458632/fetch-facebook-page-id-url-using-page-website). I don't believe this is supported.